# How to add font awesome icons on x-axis in highcharts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I have created multiple charts for dynamic data . I want to add font awesome icons on x-axis instead of displaying names. Please help on how can I add icon on x-axis instead of category, thank you.

Comment: Attaching fiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/r7b0123s/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable useHTML for the xAxis labels.

```
xAxis: {
    type:"category",
    crosshair: true,
    labels: {
        useHTML: true
    }
  },
```

and then you can use fontAwesome icons in the category names or replace the category names by icons.

```
  data: [
    ['<i class="fa fa-car"></i>  car', 10],
    ['<i class="fa fa-bus"></i>  bus', 63],
    ['<i class="fa fa-truck"></i>  truck', 50],
    ['<i class="fa fa-train"></i>  train', 54],
  ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r7b0123s/1/

Comment: actually I am working on dynamic data that is coming from server. I've added loop on data to display multiple charts, they are coming dynamically one after other. So could you please help on how can I add these icons to that data

Comment: Are you having problems dynamically creating the charts?  Or are you having problems using icons in the dynamically created charts?

Comment: Charts are already created.I am having problem using these icons in dynamically created charts

Comment: Do you have the html set for category items?   A fiddle would help explain where you are seeing problems